# Area computation comparison - terra vs. sf

Tags: r, gis, r-sf, area, terra

I'm trying to better understand how various R packages calculate areas when in lat-long geographic coordinate reference systems, and which functions provide the most accurate estimates.

The estimate of area with the s2 geometry library turned on in {sf} provides a different estimate than when s2 is turned off and GEOS is used. The {sf} GEOS area calculation is the the same as {terra}'s estimate.

Which is the most accurate way to calculate area?

```
library(terra)
library(sf)

# create a polygon using terra
p <- vect('POLYGON ((2 2, 7 6, 4 9, 2 2))', crs = 'EPSG:4326')

# calculate area with terra
expanse(p, unit = 'km')
# 165515 km2

# calculate area with sf
st_area(st_as_sf(p))/1e6
# 166235 km2

# turn off s2, then terra and sf area estimates are the same
sf_use_s2(FALSE)
round((expanse(p, unit = 'km')) - (as.numeric(st_area(st_as_sf(p))/1e6)))
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the [S2 library](https://s2geometry.io/) represents the earth as a *sphere*. The webpage states that

> the S2 library represents all data on a three-dimensional sphere

The high precision [GeographicLib](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/) uses a *spheroid* to represent the earth's shape. GeographicLib was first used by "geosphere" and it is now also used by "terra", and by "sf" when S2 is turned off.

The earth bulges at the equator and that is why you can better approximate the earth's shape with a spheroid than with a sphere. This suggests that the computation is less precise when S2 is used.

GEOS is not used in this context, as it can only be used to compute areas for planar polygons, not for lon/lat polygons.